# Navigation Buttons appears when I touch a spinner

Tags: java, android

I need help with this. I have a theme with:

```
<style name="Theme.CuentameUnCuento" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Primary brand color. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">#4CAF50</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">#388E3C</item>
    <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/white</item>
    <!-- Secondary brand color. -->
    <item name="colorSecondary">#009688</item>
    <item name="colorSecondaryVariant">#00796B</item>
    <item name="colorOnSecondary">@color/white</item>
    <!-- Status bar color. -->
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">?attr/colorPrimaryVariant</item>
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/anna</item>
</style>
```

Then I have, in the MainActivity.java, after the setContentView.

```
    View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
    int uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN;
    decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);
```

With all of this I can set the full screen mode in the app.

All seems to works fine, except when I touch a spinner adapter. Then the navigation buttons appears.
In the actitvity_main.xml the spinner:

```
<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/sp_idioma_menu"
    style="@style/spinner_style"
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="36dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/btn_salir"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    android:stateListAnimator="@null"/>
```

The styles.xml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="spinner_style">
        <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/diseny_spinner</item>
        <item name="android:paddingLeft">8dp</item>
        <item name="android:paddingRight">20dp</item>
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

The diseny_spinner.xml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item><layer-list>
        <item><shape>
        </shape></item>
    </layer-list></item>
</selector>
```

Images:
[Screenshot when I touch the Spinner](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ojyLr.png)
[Screenshot when Spinner is not opened](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FgqxL.png)

How can I solve this? Thanks

Comment: can you please provide more information?? And to show ur code you can use this :```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Sorry, I'm new here so I don't know how to do some things, I edited the post and put the code, any more just tell me please.